# Why can't I delete my own question?

Tags: discussion

So today I asked this question: https://superuser.com/questions/464472/why-do-all-my-usb-devices-malfunction-now-and-then

It was closed within an hour. Fine, OK, bad question, whatever. I'll delete it.

**Sorry**, says Super User, **you can't delete it for two days.**

This seems rather passive-aggressive to me. If I asked a bad question, and I don't care to reword it, what purpose is served by making me wait two days to delete it?

Comment: Closing decisions are easily reversible, both by moderators and regular users voting to reopen. Deletions are more difficult (as there is less visibility in comparison).

Comment: As soon as you posted the question, it was no longer *your* question. You contributed it to the community.

Comment: That rationale makes no sense, as the community quite obviously didn't want it.

Comment: @Kyralessa: That doesn't mean you get it back ;D In all seriousness, just because it was closed, doesn't mean the community doesn't want it. The question can still be improved and reopened. Closure is never final. Worst case scenario, we would have a closed question that serves as an example of what **not** to post on the site. Then, in a way, it's still welcome. Maybe tomorrow, you'll see this whole thing differently and you *want* to revise your question so it is more appropriate for the site. Cheers

Comment: @OliverSalzburg, it's hard to imagine how a community could be more unfriendly and unwelcoming than to say, "Your question is a bad one.  Now we're going to hold on to it and show it to everyone, with your name on it, as an example of what not to do."

Comment: @Kyralessa [Closures](http://superuser.com/questions/261908/why-do-some-programs-require-a-restart-after-install) are not considered [bad marks](http://superuser.com/questions/261908/why-do-some-programs-require-a-restart-after-install) against you as a user.  I'd almost garauntee that everyone has a closed question or two.  It's all a part of the learning that goes on while using Stack Exchange.

Comment: @KronoS Same link twice?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg, this is not a duplicate of that question.  I'm specifically asking about the two-day rule.

Comment: @KronoS, same for you.  This isn't a duplicate of that question.  This question is about the purpose of the two-day rule.

Comment: @DanielBeck Whoops!  That's what I get for doing copypasta Here's the [second link](http://superuser.com/questions/256845/how-do-i-share-a-folder-to-the-public-in-dropbox)

Comment: @Kyralessa The answer is the same for both question.  Therefore duplicate content.  You seem to be agitated by the actions taking place here.  At first I thought you were a new user, but I see now that you're a very experienced [SE user](http://stackexchange.com/users/3774/kyralessa).  These rules, regulations and practices shouldn't be new to you, and therefore I'm a little perplexed as to you attitude toward this whole thing.  If you have more to say, I suggest migrating this discussion over to [Ask a SU Mod](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/114/ask-a-super-user-moderator) but plz don't

Comment: take offense to the actions taking place, and assume that they are vindictively directed at you.  They aren't.

Comment: The can't-delete-for-two-days thing is completely new to me.  And there were no questions here that addressed it.  That's why I asked about it, here in this question that you decided should be closed even though the "duplicate" question has nothing to do with that matter.  (The answer to that question says nothing about *why* the two-day rule exists, which is what I was attempting to ask.)  I'm not sure what it was that brought me to SU on a whim today, but I'll try not to let it happen again.  I'll stick with SO where I feel like I understand the rules.

Comment: Interestingly, [the question was addressed on Channel 9's Defrag show today](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/The-Defrag-Show/Defrag-Clearing-Frequent-List-Keyboard-Shortcuts-Window-Always-On-Top#time=09m25s).  Skip to 9:25.

Answer (score 5):

As the other question did not address the *why* really well, let me summarize what I found on the matter.

This has already been asked on [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/):

- [How to delete closed question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/21020/how-to-delete-closed-question)

  > I would like delete a question of mine since it's been closed. Is there a way to delete a closed question? I am owner, so why am I not able to delete it the normal way? Do I have to ask some moderator?

People are usually referred to [How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that). Specifically, the section:

### When can't I delete my own post?

> You can't delete *answers* that have been [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/accepting-answers-what-is-it-all-about).
>
> You can't delete any *question* that:
>
> - has an [upvoted answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/74466/does-systematic-self-deleting-need-to-be-prevented/74471#74471), or
> - has multiple answers (even if there are no upvotes), or
> - has been [closed less than 48 hours ago](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/56149/why-cant-you-delete-your-own-recently-closed-posts) (to allow for possible reopening)
>
> You can't delete *any* of your questions or answers if you haven't *registered* your account (i.e. associated an OpenID with it).

So the reason is simply: **to allow for possible reopening**.

Comment: I had ask this also http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/103904/165346